# AttributeError: 'QgsNetworkAccessManager' object has no attribute 'setTimeout' when calling QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, attributeerror

Do you know what is causing this issue?

```py
Couldn't load plugin '_plugin' due to an error when calling its classFactory) method

AttributeError: 'QgsNetworkAccessManager' object has no attribute 'setTimeout'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-1tr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
plugins [packageName] = package. classFactory (iface)
File "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\\_init_ py", line 34, in classFactory fro import
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3-1.4/apps/qgis-1tr/./python\qgis\utils py", line 685, in
mod = builtin_import (name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\\py", line 35, in from .tools. gisbox_connection import GISBOX_CONNECTION
File "C:/PROGRA-1/QGIS3-1.4/apps/qgis-1tz/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 685, in _import
mod = builtin_import (name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\\cools\.py", line 10, in class (QObject, Logger):
File "C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\\tools\.py", line 17, in
MANAGER. setTimeout (600000)

AttributeError: 'QgsNetworkAccessManager' object has no attribute 'setTimeout'
Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0: 1bf9c5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) MSC v. 1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version: 3.4. 10-Madeira Madeira, 3d97aaae88

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles \default/python
C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3 profiles default/python/plugins
C: PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C: Program Files QGIS 3.4 bin python37.zip
C: PROGRA~1 QGIS3~1.4 apps Python37 DLLs
C: PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps Python37 Vib
C: Program Files QGIS 3.4 bin
C: PROGRA~1 QGIS3~1.4\apps Python37
C: PROGRA~1|QGIS3~1.4 apps Python37 ib site-packages
C: PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps Python37 Vib site-packages win32
C: \PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps Python37Vib \site-packages \win32Vib
C: PROGRA~1 QGIS3~1.4\apps Python37 Vib site-packages Pythonwin
C:/Users/XYZ/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles
```

I use Windows 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your QGIS 3.4 is too old. That plugin will only work in QGIS >= 3.6.

The error is:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'QgsNetworkAccessManager' object has no attribute 'setTimeout'
> ```

The [`setTimeout`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsNetworkAccessManager.html#qgis.core.QgsNetworkAccessManager.setTimeout) method was added to `QgsNetworkAccessManager` in QGIS 3.6.

You can download the latest stable release 3.28 or the most up to date point release 3.32 from [download.qgis.org](https://download.qgis.org/).

Comment: True, and also this should be raised to the plugin author. He should raise the QGIS minimum version from time to time if he knows there is a bug.